# I cannot calculate apparent wind speed. Have no Idea what's wrong. Formula is easy, but it doesn't happen to calculate it wright

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

*Formula should have and output = 12,5 with entered parameters of: wind speed = 10, true wind angle = 60, boat speed = 4 In my case it outputs: 13.458620941319543*

```
public class Direction extends Boat {
    private double trueWindAngle = 60;
    private double trueWindSpeed = 10;
    private double apparentWindAngle;
    private double apparentWindSpeed;
    private double rudPosition = 0;     // rudder position
    private double boatSpeed = 4;
    private double sailPosition = 0;    // sheet position


public void setApparentWindSpeed() {
    this.apparentWindSpeed = ApparentWindSpeed(getTrueWindSpeed(), getBoatSpeed(), trueWindAngle);
}




// W = true wind speed
// V = boat speed
// lambda = true pointing angle in degrees (0 = upwind, 180 = downwind)
//SOURCE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_wind

public double ApparentWindSpeed(double W, double V, double lambda){
    return  Math.sqrt(Math.pow(W,2) + Math.pow(V,2) + 2*W*V*Math.cos(lambda));
}
```

Comment: Cosine doesn't take degrees. It takes radians. Please see [Math API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos-double-)

Comment: Please use conventions and name your function (same as your variable) in camelCase ;)

Comment: I've tried with radians. Outcome: 6.046167175041343

Comment: Now, why do you think that number (6.04) is wrong?  Have you worked out your formula by hand with radians instead of degrees?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**It works well when convert!**

```
public class Direction extends Boat {
private double trueWindAngle = 60;
private double trueWindSpeed = 10;
private double apparentWindAngle;
private double apparentWindSpeed;
private double rudPosition = 0;     // rudder position
private double boatSpeed = 4;
private double sailPosition = 0;    // sheet position

// W = true wind speed
// V = boat speed
// lambda = true pointing angle in degrees (0 = upwind, 180 = downwind)
//SOURCE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_wind
 public void setApparentWindSpeed() {
    this.apparentWindSpeed = ApparentWindSpeed(getTrueWindSpeed(), getBoatSpeed(), Math.toRadians(trueWindAngle));
}

public double ApparentWindSpeed(double W, double V, double lambda){
    return  Math.sqrt(Math.pow(W,2) + Math.pow(V,2) + 2*W*V*Math.cos(lambda));
}
```